# Classifying the critical points of a two variables function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let
$$
f(x,y)=x\sin(xy)
$$
be a two variables function. Find and classify its critical points.

**Solution.**
I found the critical points $(0,y)$, $y\in\mathbb{R}$, but I am stuck with classifying them ($(0,0)$ should be a saddle, $(0,y)$ should be local minima for $y>0$, local maxima for $y<0$). The Hessian matrix of $f$ evaluated in $(0,0)$ is the zero matrix, while evaluated in $(0,y)$ is the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2y & 0\\ 
 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$ Hence, $(0,0)$ could be a local minima, maxima or a saddle, $(0,y)$ with $y>0$ could be local minima or saddles and $(0,y)$ with $y<0$ could be local maxima or saddles.

Answer (score 1):

To get clarity as to whether it would be a saddle point or not, you will have to go back to the basic definitions of maxima/minima. If you take an epsilon ball around the point of interest, and study the function behavior around it. Consider a point $(x,y)$ such that

$$||(x,y)|| \leq \epsilon$$

Hence

$$f(x,y) = x\sin(xy)$$

If you consider points such that $ y <0$, then $f(x,y) < f(0,0)$, else $f(x,y) > f(0,0)$

Hence, the origin is a saddle point